# Disable TinyMCE buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE Editor using the following buttons:

```
toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
toolbar2:  "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks",
toolbar4: 'contactButton | datesButton | feesButton | propertyButton'
```

toolbar4 is my default buttons. How can I disable all buttons except the print button?
My problem is that I have 2 type of users to open my editor. The first is a manager user that can edit the content, and the second user only can see and print the content.

Thanks

Comment: Which server-side language are you using?

Comment: I am using ColdFusion

Comment: You can do a server-side condition, and if it is a manager, you instantiate the editor with all buttons and if it is a normal user you instantiate the editor with the two buttons.

Comment: Do you mean that I gave to have 2 editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load TinyMCE you do so by calling `init()`...

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: textarea
   .
   .  
   .
});
```

The item you are passing to init is just a simple JavaScript object.  You can have one object that exposes all the buttons you need for editing and one object that only includes the `print` button.  When you load your page you then initialize TinyMCE appropriately based on need.  For example:

```
var normalEditor = {
  selector: textarea, 
  toolbar1: '.....',
  toolbar2: '.....',
  .
  . 
  .
}

var reducedEditor = {
  selector: textarea, 
  toolbar1: 'print',
  .
  . 
  .
}


//pseudocode
if (<user is manager>) {
    tinymce.init(normalEditor);
} else {
    tinymce.init(reducedEditor);
}
```